# Show 2 datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, datetimepicker

```
<div class="form-group" ng-if="!Unavailable">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">*{{'DepartureDate'|translate}}</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-3" ng-if="isShowdatepicker">

                            <input class="form-control "   type="text" date-picker=""  min="{{datepickerMin}}"  ng-model="book.Departure" ng-change="showDate()" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                        <div ng-if="book.FlightType=='RT'">
                        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" style="text-align: left">*{{'ReturnDate'|translate}}</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-3" ng-if="isShowdatepicker" >
                            <input class="form-control "   type="text" date-picker="" min="{{datepickerMin}}"  ng-model="book.Return"  required/>

                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The above is an HTML code, I want when I click on the first input tag and after selecting the date and time on the datetimepicker's interface, the datetimepicker interface of the second input tag will also appear if it has not been selected. (no data).
Can you guys help me to solve this problem! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not properly defining the issue but as per my understanding here is what you can do:

In order to achieve this, you can add a ng-change attribute to your first input field that triggers a function whenever a date is selected. Inside this function, you can programmatically open the date picker for the second input field if it hasn't been selected yet.

However, AngularJS itself doesn't provide a way to programmatically open a date picker, since it doesn't come with a date picker component out of the box. If you're using a third-party library for the date picker (like jQuery UI Datepicker, Angular UI Bootstrap, etc.), the method to open a date picker programmatically will depend on that library.

Below is an example with Bootstrap UI date picker.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-if="!Unavailable">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">*{{'DepartureDate'|translate}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3" ng-if="isShowdatepicker">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="book.Departure" ng-change="showDate()" is-open="departureOpened" close-text="Close" required />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div ng-if="book.FlightType=='RT'">
        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" style="text-align: left">*{{'ReturnDate'|translate}}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3" ng-if="isShowdatepicker">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="book.Return" is-open="returnOpened" close-text="Close" required />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

AngularJS code:

```
$scope.showDate = function() {
    if (!$scope.book.Return) {
        $scope.returnOpened = true;
    }
};
```

Please adjust according to the date picker you're using, the principle is to set a flag to open the date picker of the second input field when the first input field changes. Also, please consider AngularJS is an outdated technology, you might want to look into Angular (2+) or other alternatives like React or Vue.js.

Let me know if that's all what you were looking for?